# VS2017 v15.7.1 - Build | Publish creates different assembly to Build | Rebuild Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-assembly, assemblyinfo

I built a ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC WebApp using VS2017 v15.7.1.

- I set the version number in the Project settings (package section) as 1.1.1.0
- I selected Build | Configuration - Release
- I did Build | Clean followed by Build | Rebuild Solution.

When I looked at the build product .DLL in my bin/release/netcoreapp2.0 folder as expected it had product number 1.1.1 and file version 1.1.1.0. Next I performed

- Build | Publish

Then when I looked at the build product .DLL in my bin/release/netcoreapp2.0 folder it had product number and file version of 1.1.0 and 1.1.0.3.

It seems Build | Publish creates a different assembly to Build | Rebuild Solution. This behaviour is unacceptable as I need to publish the same file that I built and tested on localhost.

Any ideas anyone?

[image: screenshots]

Comment: I would guess this is a project that was ported from an earlier non-core project.  And still has an [AssemblyFileVersion] attribute in the source, formerly in AssemblyInfo.cs.  Then it gets to be a race which one will win.

Comment: Good suggestion, but not the case. I created the project using ASP.NET Core template provided by VS2017 so AssemblyInfo is set in Project Settings